# In this example, is the correct usage 'she' or 'her'?

Tags: grammatical-case, coordinating-conjunctions

In this example, is the correct usage 'she' or 'her'?

> Jenny administers the second high-dose adrenaline shot and **her** and
>   Bron change places on the table. Chest compressions are tiring, so
>   they switch to ensure they're maintaining the correct force and
>   weight.

or

> Jenny administers the second high-dose adrenaline shot and **she** and
>   Bron change places on the table. Chest compressions are tiring, so
>   they switch to ensure they're maintaining the correct force and
>   weight.

Or are both correct?

Or are both badly worded generally? In which case, how would you word such a sentence?

Comment: Forget about everything before _she_ and take that as the start.  Should it be _Her and Bron change places_ or _She and Bron change places_? If you can't answer that question, forget about answering this one.

Comment: She... OMG, I feel like I'll be sent to the headmaster's office if I get this wrong!!! Do you cane students, John? ;)

Comment: No, I try to amuse them instead. It's more fun.

Comment: LOL... well, you did! Better than a caning any day! Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construction is a compound sentence composed of two independent clauses:

Jenny administers the second high-dose adrenaline shot.

She and Bron change places on the table.

In the first clause Jenny is the subject; in the second clause "She and Bron" are the subject, so the pronoun would take the subjective case: she

Generally you would put a comma before the coordinating conjunction "and." The sentence would read, "Jenny administers the second high-dose adrenaline shot, and she and Bron change places on the table." Adding "then" to "and": "and then" would clarify the temporal aspect. If I understand the situation correctly,"at the table" might be a better choice.

Comment: thanks! Super helpful. But, no, they are on the table, straddling the patient, giving compressions. Apparently, that helps maintain the correct force and weight! Thank you!

Comment: @GGx Ah, I see. Definitely "on" the table.